# Failure while running hive query - Map operator initialization failed - OOM

Tags: hive, out-of-memory, apache-tez

I am executing hive query which is created by joining 3 tables.But I am geting below error i.e.Please let me know what this error is and how can I resolve this error.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1535088835132_0435_1_02, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1535088835132_0435_1_02_000028, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:247)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.setCapacity(Text.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.set(Text.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.<init>(Text.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableStringObjectInspector.copyObject(WritableStringObjectInspector.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils.copyToStandardObject(ObjectInspectorUtils.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils.copyToStandardObject(ObjectInspectorUtils.java:346)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.MapJoinKeyObject.read(MapJoinKeyObject.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.MapJoinKey.read(MapJoinKey.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.putRow(HashMapWrapper.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92)
    ... 4 more
], TaskAttempt 1 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:247)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable.getHiveDecimal(HiveDecimalWritable.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable.hashCode(HiveDecimalWritable.java:167)
    at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.MapJoinKeyObject.hashCode(MapJoinKeyObject.java:83)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.put(HashMapWrapper.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.putRow(HashMapWrapper.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92)
    ... 4 more
], TaskAttempt 2 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:247)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(BigDecimal.java:1202)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.createAndStripZerosToMatchScale(BigDecimal.java:4401)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros(BigDecimal.java:2598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.type.HiveDecimal.trim(HiveDecimal.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.type.HiveDecimal.normalize(HiveDecimal.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.type.HiveDecimal.create(HiveDecimal.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable.getHiveDecimal(HiveDecimalWritable.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable.hashCode(HiveDecimalWritable.java:167)
    at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.MapJoinKeyObject.hashCode(MapJoinKeyObject.java:83)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.put(HashMapWrapper.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.putRow(HashMapWrapper.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92)
    ... 4 more
], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:173)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:139)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:347)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:194)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:185)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:181)
    at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:247)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.completeInitialization(Operator.java:387)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.type.HiveDecimal.create(HiveDecimal.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable.getHiveDecimal(HiveDecimalWritable.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.HiveDecimalWritable.hashCode(HiveDecimalWritable.java:167)
    at java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Arrays.java:4146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.MapJoinKeyObject.hashCode(MapJoinKeyObject.java:83)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.put(HashMapWrapper.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.persistence.HashMapWrapper.putRow(HashMapWrapper.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HashTableLoader.load(HashTableLoader.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.loadHashTable(MapJoinOperator.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator$1.call(MapJoinOperator.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache.retrieve(ObjectCache.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ObjectCache$1.call(ObjectCache.java:92)
    ... 4 more
]], Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1 killedTasks:59, Vertex vertex_1535088835132_0435_1_02 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1535088835132_0435_1_03, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:51, Vertex vertex_1535088835132_0435_1_03 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
          (less...)
```

Comment: Without source, preferably as an [Minimal, Complete Verifyable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the log provided, you are running map join on Tez and it failed on loading hashMap. And the exception is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

Try to increase mapper container size and java heap size. Check your current configuration and increase accordingly. This is only example:

```
set hive.tez.container.size=9216;
set hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx6144m;
```

Good tuning guide with explanation about these configuration parameters can be found here: [**Demystify Apache Tez Memory Tuning - Step by Step**](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/14309/demystify-tez-tuning-step-by-step.html)
If nothing helps, maybe the table is too big to fit in memory, consider decreasing the value of `hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size` to force the query to use a Shuffle Join for the table of this big size.